# User Schema / Address Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, e-commerce, database-schema, mern

I am developing a MERN e-commerce application. In my MongoDB (I am using mongoose) I have a user schema that can have array of addresses.

I have been thinking whether I should create an Address Schema instead, so I thought I could apply further validation to Addresses

What are the advantages and disadvantages to creating an Address Schema?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you to create a schema, because it's going be easy for your access and manage it. You can create validation of your fields.